# Finding $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - (\sin x^3)^2}{\ln(1+x^{10} )}$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to solve this limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - (\sin x^3)^2}{\ln(1+x^{10} )}$$

l I tried using Taylor.

In particular:

-If I use a first order expansion on $\sin x$ the numerator becomes 0, so it is too imprecise an expansion

-If I use a second order expansion on $\sin x$, I cannot make the numerator and denominator simplify

Comment: Please do not use title lines that consist of nothing but MathJax code; they break some navigational shortcuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We might start out using the Maclaurin Expansion of $\sin x = x - \dfrac{x^3}{6} + \dfrac{x^5}{120} + o(x^5)$. Thus $\sin(x^2) = x^2 - \dfrac{x^6}{6}+\dfrac{x^{10}}{120} + o(x^{10})$, and $\sin(x^3) = x^3 - \dfrac{x^9}{6}+\dfrac{x^{15}}{120}+o(x^{15})$. It follows that $(\sin x^2)^3=x^6-\dfrac{x^{10}}{2}+o(x^{10})$, and $(\sin x^3)^2=x^6+o(x^{10})$. Using $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+x^{10})}{x^{10}}=1$, it follows that the limit is $-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

I think the taylor expansion is the way to go. The limit is equivalent to

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {(x^2 - \frac 16 x^6+ \cdots)^3 - (x^3 - \frac 16 x^9 + \cdots)^2}{x^{10}-x^{20} + \cdots}$$

When we multiply out the exponentials in the numerator any terms of degree greater than 10, we can ignore. Consequently, we obtain,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac { (x^6 - \frac 36 x^{10} + \cdots) - (x^6 - \frac 26 x^{12}+ \cdots)}{x^{10} + \cdots} = -\frac {1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log (1+t)}{t}=1$$ we can replace the denominator by $x^{10}$ and hence the limit in question is equal to the limit of $$\frac{(\sin x^2)^3-(\sin x^3)^2}{x^{10}}$$ Adding and subtracting $x^6$ in numerator we get $$\frac {(\sin x^2)^3-x^6}{x^{10}}-\frac {(\sin x^3) ^2-x^6}{x^{10}}\tag{1}$$ The second fraction can be written as $$x^2\cdot\frac{\sin x^3-x^3}{x^9}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin x^3}{x^3}+1\right)$$ and this tends to $0\cdot(-1/6)\cdot 2=0$. We can write the first fraction in $(1)$ as $$\frac{\sin x^2-x^2}{x^6}\cdot\left(\frac{(\sin x^2)^2}{x^4}+\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}+1\right)$$ and this tends to $(-1/6)\cdot 3=-1/2$. Hence the desired limit is $-1/2$. We have used the fact that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t - t} {t^3}=-\frac{1}{6}$$ (this can be established either using l'Hospital's Rule or Taylor expansions).

Comment: I had the exactly the same idea after I saw your first try!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative by standard limits

$$\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - (\sin x^3)^2}{\ln(1+x^{10} )}=\frac{x^{10}}{\ln(1+x^{10} )}\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - (\sin x^3)^2}{x^{10} }$$

with $\frac{x^{10}}{\ln(1+x^{10} )} \to 1$ and

$$\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - (\sin x^3)^2}{x^{10} }=\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - x^6}{x^{10} }-\frac{(\sin x^3)^2-x^6}{x^{10} }\to -\frac12$$

indeed using that $\frac{\sin x -x}{x^3} \to -\frac 16$

$$\frac{(\sin x^2)^3 - x^6}{x^{10} }=\frac{\sin x^2 - x^2}{x^{6} }\frac{(\sin x^2)^2 +x^2\sin x^2+x^4}{x^{4} }\to -\frac16 \cdot 3 =-\frac12$$

and

$$\frac{(\sin x^3)^2-x^6}{x^{10} }=\frac{\sin x^3-x^3}{x^{9} }\frac{\sin x^3+x^3}{x } \to -\frac 1 6 \cdot 0=0$$

Comment: This is the same as my answer. Perhaps you didn't notice it.

Comment: Hello Paramanand! I've write it down while you were editing your one, I saw your previous version deleted at that time (which was pretty different)! This is a genuine copy, but I can delete it of course is it is superfluous or there is something bad with it! Thanks Bye!